# How to restrict the number of child actors to create

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have an actor that does the following:

1. connect to a database, and fetch the top 100 rows from a table
2. create a child actor for each row.  Some actors will complete processing before the others potentially
3. go back to #1 and fetch more rows

Now I want to limit the # of child actors to e.g. 100.

There are 2 options here:

1. Wait till all child actors have completed then go to step #1 and fetch the next 100 rows.
2. Somehow keep track of the # of child actors, and fetch more rows as the child actors free up

How would I go about designing #2? (keeping track of free actors and fetch as they are available)

Comment: Why not use an [actor pool](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html)?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov interesting, but I want the pool size etc. to be determined dynamically so I can change it will running i.e. storing config in a database that can be updated on the fly.  that looks like it is config file driven no?

Comment: How often does it change? Can you determine it based on startup time?

Comment: You can create pull dynamically `context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[Worker]), "router2")`